# PSRemoting (Using SSL) from Docker Container to HostMachine

Tags: powershell, docker, ssl, containers, powershell-remoting

**Goal**: Secure Powershell Remoting to Communicate from Docker Container (Windows Server Core) to Host Machine (Windows 10).

I am trying to communicate from Docker Container to Hostmachine to run Powershell commands. PS Remoting looked promising. I did a little POC and It works simply using HTTP. I just pass in the Credentials and everything seems to work fine. However, I am having hard time securing the PS Remoting using SSL.

I followed [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-over-https-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate/) to secure the PS Remoting.

Like below

`$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "passwordstring" -AsPlainText -Force
 $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username string", $password)
 Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "ComputerName" -UseSSL -Credential $Cred`

**Expected**: Powershell Remoting to Work -UsingSSL

**Actual**:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server DESKTOP-T773322.mshome.net failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
>   For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DESKTOP-T773322.mshome.net -UseSSL -Cre ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DESKTOP-T773322.mshome.net:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

I am able to get the -UseSSL working from a VM to my Local Machine. but not Docker Container to Host Machine.

**Things I tried**:

1. Turn off all Windows Firewalls.
2. Ping works both ways (From Container to Host and Vice versa).
3. Ran `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.PowerShell` to verify if the User has enough permissions to Remote Connect.
4. Restart Machine.
5. Added the Container Machine to trusted Hosts.
6. Changed Trusted Hosts Value to *(all).

*Note: The end goal here is to communicate from Docker Container to Local Host Machine. So, It can run Powershell Commands/Batch Files on the Host machine (Securely - Using SSL). I have not found an alternative other than PS Remoting. Please suggest me if there is another better way to do this.*